# Add the value of each column in the sliced values

Tags: c++, arrays, string, byte, slice

I want to add the value of each column in the sliced values.i'd like to get the sum of every column. Can you help me?

```
int main(void)
{
    char serial[] = "XQXQT6FM6YNN26PNRM1S7QRESA0W01TV";
    
    //get length of serial 
    int len_key = strlen(serial);
    BYTE arr[len_key];
    int i;

    //converting string to BYTE[]
    SerialtoByte(serial, arr);
    
    for(i=0; i<len_key; i++)
    {
        cout<<" "<<arr[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    sliceKey(arr);
    cout<<"\n\n";
}
```

**byte value**

```
88 81 88 81 84 54 70 77 54 89 78 78 50 54 80 78 82 77 49 83 55 81 82 69 83 65 48 87 48 49 84 86
```

**this is the sliced value**

```
88 81 88 81 84 54 70 77 
54 89 78 78 50 54 80 78 
82 77 49 83 55 81 82 69 
83 65 48 87 48 49 84 86
```

Comment: You want to do something, and you have code for it. What's the question? What specifically do you want help with?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is one way to do it, using modulo operator:

```cpp
int sumOfColumnValue[8] = {0};
for(i=0; i < len_key; i++)
{
    sumOfColumnValue[i % 8] += arr[i];
}
// print the first column's sum:
std::cout << sumOfColumnValue[0];
```

Comment: @LemuelFajarda I've edited my answer.